# Linq select in select

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework, linq

I am struggling with converting MySQL query to linq syntax in C# (for use of Entity Framework). MySQL query looks like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM Availability as tableData
WHERE ID = (
SELECT Availability.ID 
FROM Availability 
WHERE Availability.FrameID = tableData.FrameID 
ORDER BY Availability.Date DESC limit 1)
```

I don't know how to convert this part `FROM table AS someName`.

So far the only solution I have, is to execute raw SQL query such as:

```
dataContext.Availability.SqlQuery("SELECT * FROM Availability as tableData WHERE ID = (SELECT ID FROM Availability WHERE FrameID = tableData.FrameID ORDER BY Availability.Date DESC limit 1)").ToArray();
```

But it would be nice to know if linq can provide such a query.

Thanks in advance, for your answers!

Comment: What the point of sub-query here?

Comment: I need only one record (with max Date of insert) for every FrameID

Comment: Grabbing one Entity by an ID would be as simple as: entity = context.Table.Find(id); in Linq.  Am I missing something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need only latest record for every frame id, then use grouping:

```
dataContext.Availability
   .GroupBy(a => a.FrameID)
   .Select(g => g.OrderByDescending(a => a.Date).FirstOrDefault());
```

This query produces required result, though generated sql will be a little different. It will look like

```
SELECT /* limit1 fields */
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT tableData.FrameID
    FROM Availability as tableData) AS distinct1
OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT TOP(1) /* project1 fields */
    FROM (SELECT /* extent1 fields */
          FROM Availability AS extent1
          WHERE Availability.FrameID = distinct1.FrameID) AS project1
    ORDER BY project1.Date DESC) AS limit1
```

NOTE: `First()` extension is not supported by EF

Answer (score 2):

Take all the Avilabilities, group by FrameId, order each group by date, take the first entry of each group. 
The ToList() at the end fetches all the results and puts them in a List.

```
var tableDate = dataContext.Availability
               .GroupBy(x => x.FrameId)
               .Select(x => x.OrderByDescending(y => y.Date).FirstOrDefault())
               .ToList();
```

Comment: as @SergeyBerezovskiy posted First() is not supported by EF. But with FirstOrDefault() it works. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Yes Linq can do this, but you need to have a starting sequence on which the linq should operate. Usually this sequence has the same type as your table, in your case Availability.

From your sql I gather that each record in the Availabilities table has at least properties Id, FrameId and Date:

```
class Availability
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public int FrameId {get; set;
    public DateTime Date {get; set;}
}
```

Of course this can also be an anonymous type. The importance is that you have somehow a sequence of items having these properties:

```
IQueryable<Availability> availabilities = ...
```

You wrote:

> I need only one record (with max Date of insert) for every FrameID

So every Availability has a FrameId, and you want for every FrameId the record with the highest Date value.

You could use [Enumerable.GroupBy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534304(v=vs.110).aspx) and group by FrameId

```
var groupsWithSameFrameId = availabilities.GroupBy(availability => availability.FrameId);
```

The result is a sequence of groups. Every group contains the sequence of all availabilities with the same FrameId. In other words: if you take a group, you'll have a group.Key with a FrameId value and a sequence of all availabilities that have this FrameId value.

We won't use the group.Key.
If you sort the sequence of elements in each group in descending order by Date and take the first element, you'll have the date with the highest value

```
var recordWithMaxDateOfInsert = groupsWithSameFrameId
    .Select(group => group.OrderByDescending(groupElement => groupElement.Date)
    .First();
```

> From every group sort all elements of the group by descending Date value and take the first element of the sorted group.

Result: from your original availabilities, you have for every frameId the availability with the highest value for date.